# How to share .MOBI file to drop box using Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios

How can we share the files to another app using Xamarin iOS like intent in Xamarin Android?
I want to share the files to drop box and ibooks in button click using xamarin ios. How can we achieve this?